# Existence of weights of a finite dimensional representation of a semisimple Lie algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a semisimple complex Lie algebra.

I want to show that every finite dimensional irreducible representation of $\mathfrak{g}$ is a weight module, and I need the existence of at least one weight (which would imply that the sum over all weight spaces is a nontrivial subrepresentation, and hence the representation itself).

In the $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{sl}_2$ case, this is easy since the cartan subalgebra is one dimensional and the ground field is algebraically closed, but I don't know how to find an eigenvector in the general setting. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Isn't the idea the same? Given matrices $A_1,\ldots,A_n$, that are diagonalizable and simultaneously commute, they are simultaneously diagonlizable. By Ado's theorem, you can think of $\mathfrak{g}$ as a subalgebra of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$.